# UIImagePickerController show black screen for every second shot

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, ios8, uiimagepickercontroller

On all iOS 8 devices I'm facing a new issue when I'm using the UIImagePickerController (on iOS 7 it's working fine).
The first shot works as expected. When I try to to take another photo the UIImagePickerController appears but shows a black screen.

All the controls such as switch camera, cancel and take photo button are available and working. If I try to make the second photo and touch the button I get a correct preview of the taken photo. If I save that photo and try to make another one all behaves as expected. Only the fourth photo has the same issue again. And so on...

This is my code:

```cs
public void ButtonCameraClicked(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    _imagePickerDelegate = new ImagePickerControllerDelegate(this);
    _imagePicker = new UIImagePickerController();
    _imagePicker.ImagePickerControllerDelegate = _imagePickerDelegate;

    if (UIImagePickerController.IsSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera))
        _imagePicker.SourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera;
    else
        _imagePicker.SourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary;

    PresentViewController(_imagePicker, true, null);
}

public override void FinishedPickingMedia(UIImagePickerController picker, NSDictionary info)
{
    BTProgressHUD.Show("Bild wird gespeichert...");
    var image = (UIImage)info.ObjectForKey(new NSString("UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"));
    image.SaveToCustomPhotosAlbum(info[UIImagePickerController.MediaMetadata] as NSDictionary, _controller.AlbumName, _controller.MediaSaved);
    picker.DismissViewController(true, null);
}
```

I've already googled a lot an tried the following things without any success

**Initializing just once**

```cs
if (_imagePicker == null)
{
    _imagePickerDelegate = new ImagePickerControllerDelegate(this);
    _imagePicker = new UIImagePickerController();
    _imagePicker.ImagePickerControllerDelegate = _imagePickerDelegate;
}
```

**Or using a completion block**

```cs
PresentViewController(_imagePicker, true, () => { });

PresentViewController(_imagePicker, true, () => { Thread.Sleep(300); });
```

**Or synchronising to main thread**

```cs
InvokeOnMainThread(() => { ... });` 
`NSOperationQueue.MainQueue.AddOperation(() => { ... });
```

The whole code file is available on: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/83a855d44d697235849b

Comment: I had the same problem. Resizing and saving the image in another queue using dispatch_async helped. The camera preview needs the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything you tried and then decided to go a different route. The Xamarin.Mobile component on the component store not only provides a cross platform implementation of camera but in my testing was not subject to the same iOS 7+ black preview screen problem.

**Sample Usage from** https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/xamarin.mobile

```
using Xamarin.Media;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
//...


var picker = new MediaPicker();
MediaPickerController controller = picker.GetTakePhotoUI (new StoreCameraMediaOptions {
   Name = "test.jpg",
   Directory = "MediaPickerSample"
});

// On iPad, you'll use UIPopoverController to present the controller
PresentViewController (controller, true, null);

controller.GetResultAsync().ContinueWith (t => {
// Dismiss the UI yourself
   controller.DismissViewController (true, () => {
    //might want to add if(t.Result.Status = task.enumstatus.rantocompletion)
    //or camera cancels will throw exceptions
    MediaFile file = t.Result;
    });

}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```